# Change background of Cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I want to change the background color of a specific cell to match the color of the text.
For example, the "Red" cell would have a red background and so on.
Im having difficulty in figuring out what code to place. Any suggestions?

import UIKit

```
class PedsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var PENames = [String] ()
    var PEIdentities = [String] ()
    var PEDetail = [String] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        PENames = ["Green","Orange","Blue","White","Yellow","Purple","Red","Pink"]
        PEIdentities = ["Green","Orange","Blue","White","Yellow","Purple","Red","Pink"]
        PEDetail = ["Green","Orange","Blue","White","Yellow","Purple","Red","Pink"]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return PENames.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PECell")

        cell?.textLabel!.text = PENames[indexPath.row]

        cell?.detailTextLabel!.text = PEDetail[indexPath.row]


        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vcName = PEIdentities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: (vcName))
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array with matching colors:

```
var colors = [UIColor]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  colors = [.green, .orange ... ]
}
```

Then, just set the color in the cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PECell")

  ..

  cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]
  return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
let selectedColor: UIColor = .red

cell?.backgroundColor = selectedColor
```

Comment: While I thought about that, it doesnt allow me to customize a color for each cell. Only the whole table.